# Is there a "Start without debugging" equivalent for the command-line outside Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, command-line, visual-studio-2017

There's a backend API, a .Net Core application, I need to have running in the background while working on the frontend. It works to open the API in Visual Studio, and then hit "Start [without] debugging", but that means Visual Studio is running in the background unnecessarily.

I've tried to figure out if I can just build the project and run it somehow, but can't quite figure out how to do that, but either way, I'd like to not have to figure that out.

Because, what I'd like to do, is basically "Start without debugging" from the command-line, and have it do whatever it currently does *in* Visual Studio by default, to make it run.

Is this possible? Is there a command-line equivalent of "Start without debugging" that does everything Visual Studio does?

Comment: `dotnet run`...?

Comment: [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run?tabs=netcore21) for `dotnet run`.

Comment: @CodeCaster But what are equivalent parameters for `dotnet run`? What is it running exactly? Can it figure out what to do from an sln or csproj somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out, thanks to the comments from @codecaster and @kirk-larkin:

```
> dotnet run --project path\to\some.csproj
```

Apparently much easier than I thought.